# urlib.urlretrieve and urlib2 corrupting files

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I've run into a frustrating stumbling block with an XBMC extension I'm working on.

In summary, if I download a file using Firefox, IE, etc then the file is valid and works fine but if I use urlib or urlib2 in python then the file is corrupted.

The file in question is: http://re.zoink.it/00b007c479 (007960DAD4832AC714C465E207055F2BE18CAFF6.torrent)

Here are the checksums:

```
PY: 2d1528151c62526742ce470a01362ab8ea71e0a7
IE: 60a93c309cae84a984bc42820e6741e4f702dc21
```

Checksum mis-match (Python DL is corrupt, IE/FF DL is not corrupt)

Here's the function that I've written to do this task

```
def DownloadFile(uri, localpath):
  '''Downloads a file from the specified Uri to the local system.

  Keyword arguments:
  uri -- the remote uri to the resource to download
  localpath -- the local path to save the downloaded resource 
  '''
  remotefile = urllib2.urlopen(uri)
  # Get the filename from the content-disposition header
  cdHeader = remotefile.info()['content-disposition']

  # typical header looks like: 'attachment;   filename="Boardwalk.Empire.S05E00.The.Final.Shot.720p.HDTV.x264-BATV.[eztv].torrent"'
  # use RegEx to slice out the part we want (filename)
  filename = re.findall('filename=\"(.*?)\"', cdHeader)[0]    
  filepath = os.path.join(localpath, filename)
  if (os.path.exists(filepath)):
      return

  data = remotefile.read()
  with open(filepath, "wb") as code:
    code.write(data) # this is resulting in a corrupted file

  #this is resulting in a corrupted file as well
  #urllib.urlretrieve(uri, filepath)
```

What am I doing wrong? Its hit or miss; some sources download correctly and others always result in a corrupted file if I download with python. They all seem to download correctly is I use a web browser

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is Gzip-encoded:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> remotefile = urllib2.urlopen('http://re.zoink.it/00b007c479')
>>> remotefile.info()['content-encoding']
'gzip'
```

Your browser decodes this for you, but `urllib2` does not. You'll need to do this yourself first:

```
import zlib

data = remotefile.read()
if remotefile.info().get('content-encoding') == 'gzip':
    data = zlib.decompress(data, zlib.MAX_WBITS + 16)
```

Once decompressed the data fits your SHA1 signature perfectly:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> import hashlib
>>> data = remotefile.read()
>>> hashlib.sha1(data).hexdigest()
'2d1528151c62526742ce470a01362ab8ea71e0a7'
>>> hashlib.sha1(zlib.decompress(data, zlib.MAX_WBITS + 16)).hexdigest()
'60a93c309cae84a984bc42820e6741e4f702dc21'
```

You probably want to switch to using the [`requests` module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/), which handles content encoding transparently:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://re.zoink.it/00b007c479')
>>> hashlib.sha1(response.content).hexdigest()
'60a93c309cae84a984bc42820e6741e4f702dc21'
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I just dumped the headers and immediately noticed the gzip encoding (http://s12.postimg.org/x1f33j8kd/content_encoding.jpg). Arg... how frustrating.

Comment: @NealBailey: in this specific case the server appears to ignore the `Accept-Encoding` header (I tried sending an empty header, as well as set it to `identity`, and the server still used `gzip` encoding, tsk. tsk.), but in other cases setting that header should help avoid the issue.